# how to get list of possible numbers with given number of factors in python?

Tags: python, factors

I can get the factors and number of factors of a given number:

```
def all_factors(x):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return factors
print(all_factors(320))
print(len(all_factors(320)))
```

It gives the following output:

> [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16, 20, 32, 40, 64, 80, 160, 320]
>
> 14

But, how can I do the reverse of it?
For example: If I have number of factors = 4, the possible list must be [6, 10, 14, 21, ...] where we can limit the maximum integer in the list.

Comment: `[n for n in range(N) if len(all_factors(n))==4]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code** Using your all_factors code

```
def reverse_factors(n, max_):
  # Loops through numbers from 1 to max_ to check
  # number of factors. Keeps the ones with the desired 
  # number of factors as determined by len(all_factors(x))
  return [x for x in range(1, max_+1) if len(all_factors(x))  == n]
```

**Test**

```
# Numbers with 4 factors up to 30
print(reverse_factors(4, 30))
```

**Output**

```
[6, 8, 10, 14, 15, 21, 22, 26, 27]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
n =int(input("Enter the limit: "))
factno = int(input("No of factors: ")) # here 4
listing = []
for i in range(1,n+1):
    #Your code here to find factors and to add then to a list named "factors'
    factors = []
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        if i % j == 0:
            factors.append(j)
    if len(factors) == factno:
        listing.append(i)
print(listing)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
def all_factors(x, number_factors):
    factors = []

    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if len(factors) == number_factors:
            break 

        if x % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return factors
```